# JavaCard Proactive handler busy

Tags: java, android, applet, javacard

I develop SIM applet. It can show a menu (PRO_CMD_SELECT_ITEM) or message (PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT) when SIM receives binary SMS.
On Android phones, there is a problem. 
When message or menu shows- user presses ok or back- everything is ok, but if user presses "home", applet doesn't receive answer and, when I try to use proactive commands- applet can't get proactive handler.

```
try{
hdlr = ProactiveHandler.getTheHandler();
}
catch (ToolkitException e)
{
    somevariable = (byte)e.getReason(); 
}
```

after executing, somevariable becomes 2

```
static short    HANDLER_NOT_AVAILABLE 
This reason code (= 2) is used to indicate that the Handler is not available (e.g. busy).
```

Same happens when applet shows menu and user presses "home" - ProactiveHandler becomes busy

Is there any in-applet way to make ProactiveHandler available?

Comment: are able to see terminal response when you press home button?

Comment: Sorry, I can't check if there is a terminal response. It's communication between phone and SIM

Comment: Proactive handler can only be busy if last command's terminal response is not arrived yet.by the way are you incoming sms in applet?

Comment: @AnuragSharma Then, looks like when user presses "home", no terminal response is sent. Yes, I receive incoming SMS by EVENT_FORMATTED_SMS_PP_ENV and applet can do anything except proactive commands

Comment: yes you are right...when you press home button terminal response is not received and display text goes to background.Try changing qualifier to CLEAR_AFTER_DELAY of display text.It may solve your problem.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Thanks, i forgot about that qualifier. But that's only half of problem. PRO_CMD_SELECT_ITEM doesn't have qualifier like CLEAR_AFTER_DELAY =(

Comment: you can use EVENT proative handler available in this case.Please read https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/10396073/ts-102-241-v780-smart-cards-uicc-application-etsi/15

Comment: you have to wait for NO_USER_ACTIVITY terminal response from the phone then EVENT proative handler available will trigger and u can perform ur task.

Comment: @AnuragSharma That's a good idea, but I use JC 2.1.2, there's no such event here. But it doesn't matter, because I still can use EVENT_STATUS_COMMAND and check if ProactiveHandler is available. But, as far as I see, ProactiveHandler becomes available only after phone reset

Comment: then you can use refresh command after few status and when handler is busy.And look in toolkit release 6 for "EVENT proative handler available " event.

Comment: Hi Greenisha, Does refresh command solved your problem?

Comment: @AnuragSharma Thanks for your answer, but I tried REFRESH before- it does'nt work because it is proactive command, to use it I have to get ProactiveHandler, which is busy

Comment: Oh yes :( then you are totaly dependent on phone if it is not sending terminal response.

Comment: But mobile should provide No response from user(0x12)as terminal response.You can consider this as a buggy mobile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62170/discussion-between-anurag-sharma-and-greenisha).